# Как лучше обращаться к объекту-менеджеру?

Tags: c#, unity3d

В продолжение моего вопроса про кэширивание при столкновениях. У меня на объекте-менеджере висит скрипт с:

```
private static MyManagerScript instance;
public static MyManagerScript Instance 
{
    get {
        if (instance == null) 
        {
            instance = GameObject.FindObjectOfType<MyManagerScript> ();
        }
        return MyManagerScript.instance; }
}
```

Как лучше обращаться к этому менеджеру в каком-либо объекте? Вариант 1:

```
// напрямую?
    MyManagerScript.Instance.SomeInt;
```

Или вариант 2:

```
private int myInt;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    myInt = PauseManagerScript.instance.SomeInt;
}

// и уже работать с myInt вместо PauseManagerScript.instance.SomeInt
// А затем, если нужно, делать PauseManagerScript.instance.SomeInt = myInt
```

Comment: `private static` для поля может не хватить, попробуйте добавить признак `volatile` если вам нужно что б все потоки видели ваш instance.

Comment: @nick_n_a хм, а если у меня в менеджере `public int SomeInt 
 {
  get { return paused; }
 }`, т.е никакой объект не может изменять значения в менеджере, а только получает их? То есть `А затем, если нужно, делать PauseManagerScript.instance.SomeInt = myInt` отменяется

Comment: Вот [здесь](http://www.pic24.ru/doku.php/osa/articles/volatile_for_chainiks) отличная статья про `volatile`. Она ориентирована на программистов С++, но объяснения должны быть понятны.

Answer (score 3):

Если ты вводишь синглтон, то, видимо, тебе для чего-то это нужно.
В своём примере ты можешь спокойно использовать любой из подходов. Разница начнётся в тот момент, когда время жизни инстанса синглтона станет меньше времени жизни твоего бехавиора. В этом случае одни объекты будут работать с одним экземпляром, а твой скрипт - с другим.

И вот тут возникает проблема связанная с тем, что ты не знаешь - чем ограничено время жизни статичных объектов в Unity, а мы не знаем - является ли твой менеджер объектом жизненного цикла Unity или нет. Прочитай об этом сам или детализируй вопрос.

Если менеджер является наследником Component, то твоя реализация неверна. Необходимо вызвать для него метод `DontDestroyOnLoad`, в противном случае он будет исключён из обработки событий Unity. Вот [пример реализации](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/Singleton).

Comment: То есть, если менеджер и объект, который получает к нему доступ, находятся на `Scene 1`, и при этом они существуют только на этой сцене (то есть, никакой объект, который находится на другой сцене, не пытается получить доступ к моему менеджеру), то вообще не важно, обращаться к нему напрямую или кэшировать?

Comment: В случае правильной реализации (по ссылке выше) разницы не будет. В случае неправильной, у тебя выгрузится AppDomain и ты создашь новый экземпляр инстанса в своём синглтоне и код продолжит работать с разными объектами.